# Android set external image as background of the view programatically

Tags: android

I want to set external image (e.g. https://www.google.ge/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_120x44dp.png) as background of the view without saving it on the device.

One way I could think of is downloading the image on sdcard, setting it as background and deleting it afterwards, but there must be the better approach.

What is the best way to achieve this in Android? Could anybody provide the working function?

Comment: You can use image loader library like Universal Image Loader/Picasso. Basically they cache the image internally rather saving it on sd card.

Comment: do you want to reuse the image again in your program or is it used just once for a particular activity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/). It will cache the image.

Here is a sample code,

```
Picasso.with(context)
    .load("https://www.google.ge/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_120x44dp.png")
    .into(imageView);
```

Answer (score 1):

Hey please go through [lazy loading](https://github.com/thest1/LazyList). This library saves images as cache and delete them after sometime.